# Weslock deadlatch is stuck

Tags: lock

We have a weslock lock on the door to our garage (bought about 2 years ago), and it has gotton stuck. It would not open from the inside or outside. The key turns ok, and even makes the click sound, but the latch will not open. We ended up unscrewing the screws. The front and back came off but the deadlatch is stuck there and we can't get it out. Any tips will help.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Try pushing on the door, to relieve any pressure that may be jamming the latch. Do the knobs turn?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We have tried pushing the door -- up, down, forward, backward. When the knobs were on, they were not turning even though the key was turning within the knob.  Now the front and back of the knob are unscrewed and taken out, but the deadlatch is still jammed there.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have the lock cylinder and the knob removed try to insert a screwdriver into the deadbolt mechanism and rotate it. This should retract the dead bolt. Failing that, remove the hinge pins, slide the door out of the frame and remove the deadbolt retaining screws on the edge of the door.